# Firebase Auth Internal Error on login attempt

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are an app that uses firebase to create and sign in users. The sign in worked fine before, but recently it started giving an "Internal Error" (in the picture below) whenever we try to sign in with an email and password

I checked to make sure that the sign in method (email and password) was enabled on firebase

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: signInEmail.text!, password: signInPassword.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
    if(error == nil) {
        print("SUCCESS: User authenticated with firebase")
        if let user = user {
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(user.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
            print("SUCCESS: Data saved to keychain")
        }
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        print("Debug Description")
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

This is the debug Description that comes up

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x2835ccbd0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    displayName = "";
    email = "lilhughes12@gmail.com";
    expiresIn = 3600;
    idToken ="eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjU0OGYzZjk4N2IxNzMxOWZlZDhjZDc2ODNmNTIyNWEyOTY0YzY5OWQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vbXJwYXJ0eS05MTNkMiIsImF1ZCI6Im1ycGFydHktOTEzZDIiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NjA2NDc2MzcsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJ3aDlDQkdCYk1uY2Rvd044aUdXRVN0bXVlMk0yIiwic3ViIjoid2g5Q0JHQmJNbmNkb3dOOGlHV0VTdG11ZTJNMiIsImlhdCI6MTU2MDY0NzYzNywiZXhwIjoxNTYwNjUxMjM3LCJlbWFpbCI6ImxpbGh1Z2hlczEyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJsaWxodWdoZXMxMkBnbWFpbC5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.i2qRZuZPPnxpKVN-4mWVwG8dZuTMvc10QV3MxzB_La_FBNqpBrErTPjGF9PiUSOtV60YpSFKtLTFdcS5GixvN3DCvVs8OxpGBykPyoS6c4ronm9Q0hU0nK8Mc_8Ahpkq9FZkfTGdTrVyUOM9j3gs8fhFOqa5mw-1u4mNNF_lQitt1xL2FuQeXhFNMYJm14HVxlKQh0Bxb_b7ogdjOzw1BcHsTsz0zLwWx-BTqOc6jyArCSZdTBJ4x-bgSl1m-JxinOUiTMATUdB9hnXRMZEUfd1s6hL6EvpZsT95Yxfgnu8sx1yOTbApRmNYR6TGDZjXDTjpY0mUqP-_YWD7V1yY4g";
    kind = "identitytoolkit#SignInWithPasswordResponse";
    localId = wh9CBGBbMncdowN8iGWEStmue2M2;
    refreshToken = "AEu4IL0vI7r7MpOLHLKNYUP8EH1i85KB8NUUA4PXSkYBa8Gmf7HhW77tqAU1aL3_zlPRdcIqrQR023l-X7mCoZe8MYgabwBXb9q9z23j7UtPAwk4QMNByOg97xqaNLejucqAXEDS2LkrvL1Ql58E1fDme4DdY4767kKj3ITrunym9HlbgVjBY4xJMZZyAS8tCFeMI8DQoEkJaNw5s_Wjs7bAejLfTjxjHw";
    registered = 1;
    }}}})
```

Comment: It's possible you're retrieving the wrong App ID. Try downloading and installing the GoogleService-Info.plist. Also watch out for force-unwrapping those optionals. Also you  may want to update your Firebase libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the limited code you provided, it looks like you are using Firebase version 3.11.0 and FirebaseAuth version 3.1.1. As of the most recent update to Firebase, the Sign In With Email function is no longer functional. In order to resolve this issue, you are going to have to update Firebase and FirebaseAuth to their latest versions (6.2.0 and 6.1.1 respectively).

In order to update your pods, go to your project folder in terminal and type `pod update`. This process may take a few minutes (depending on your computer and connectivity). After your pods have been updated, resolve all the compilation errors and you should be all set!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the issue by performing:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database' , '~> 5.0'
```

And running a `pod update`.