# Firebase PhoneAuth Error for some users in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase Phone Auth for my both iOS and Android apps. There is no problem in Android. but in iOS some users can not log in and get error description as ;

"An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."

I don't see this error when I debug, but some users face this issue some users don't.  And when I use same number in my devices it works.

Is there anyone who faced same issue or who knows the fix way?

Comment: make sure the phone num starts with its country code

Comment: yes nums are starting with country code. when I try same num in my devices, it works

Comment: You are implementing phoneAuth by recaptcha or Silent push notification ?

Comment: I use recaptcha

Comment: then make sure that your pod are fully updated there is nothing that i could figure out that is causing the error.

Comment: refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615364/firebase-auth-internal-error-on-login-attempt hope it will help you